# jQuery validation with checkboxes scenario with 2 sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, checkbox

I have a question about a confusing jQuery validation with checkboxes problem.

I have a form that has two headings:

The issue: Under the "Heading 1", one option must be selected and under "Heading 2" one option must be selected.

`<input type="checkbox" id="commjoin" name="commjoin"/>` THROUGH `<input type="checkbox" id="commjoin11" name="commjoin11"/>` is under "Heading 1".

```
Heading 1
checkbox
checkbox
checkbox
checkbox
checkbox
checkbox
```

`<input type="checkbox" id="commjoin12" name="commjoin12"/>` THROUGH `<input type="checkbox" id="commjoin50" name="commjoin50"/>` is under "Heading 2".

```
Heading 2
checkbox
checkbox
checkbox
checkbox
checkbox
checkbox
```

This needs to be checked when the "Next" button is clicked `<input type="submit" name="button" onclick="return ckFormJ(5);  "  runat=server id="button" value="Next >>">`

To reiterate, under the "Heading 1" one option must be selected and under "Heading 2" one option must be selected.

I could see how to see if one box is checked maybe but to validate if at least one box is checked under each heading is a bit more difficult. How could I go about getting this to work?

Hi,
I wrapped each group in a div tag so that I can then check each group for at least one box checked but for some reason I can't get it working.

CODE BELOW NOT SHOWING UP RIGHT; How do I post HTML?

Chemistry/Urinalysis
                
            
            
                $0.00
            
            
                        
            
                                       

        
            
                Education
                
            
            
                $0.00
            
            
                        
            
                                       

        
            
                Generalist
                
            
            
                $0.00
            
            
                        
            
                                       

        
            
                Hematology/Hemostasis
                
            
            
                $0.00
            
            
                        
            
                                       
                                                              



        
            
                Alabama State Society
                
            
            
                $10.00
            
            
                      
            
                                       

        
            
                Alaska State Society
                
            
            
                $0.00
            
            
                      
            
                                       

        
            
                Arizona/Nevada State Society
                
            
            
                $0.00
            
            
                      
            
                                       

        
            
                Arkansas State Society
                
            
            
                $0.00

JQUERY shows up fine:
$("input[type=submit]").click(function () {

```
var length1 = $('#Scientific Assembly input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
alert("length1=" + length1);

var length2 = $('#State Societies input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
alert("length2=" + length2);

if (length1 == 0) {
    alert("Please select at least one Scientific Assembly checkbox");
    return false;
}

if (length2 == 0) {
    alert("Please select at least one State Societies checkbox");
    return false;
}
return true;
```

});

Comment: Can you post some code?  You don't need a screenshot-- copy paste is fine.

Comment: would you please add up a fiddle?

Comment: you could get a better solution, if you post your actual HTML (whatever is necessary)

Comment: I tried to add a short example of the code but it keeps telling me to add context. Not sure WTF that means as its a plain table of code with comments on what it is..... Can;t get paste that validation so I can't add the HTML to this post.

Here is a link right to it much easier:
http://files.mbdevpro.com/CheckboxesCODE.html

Answer (score 0):

The question is not worded well. Nonetheless, the OP is asking if you have a checkbox group spread across different heading tags...how do you make sure at lease one box is selected per heading.

### Solution

- Wrap checkbox sections in a tag
- checkbox onchange check length of selected checkboxes per section
- compare selection.length >= 1 per section
- do something on valid

**Live Example**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RagaML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>heading 1</h1>
        <fieldset id="area1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="test"> Box1
            <input type="checkbox" name="test"> Box2
        </fieldset>

        <h1>heading 2</h1>
        <fieldset id="area2">
            <input type="checkbox" name="test"> Box3
            <input type="checkbox" name="test"> Box4
        </fieldset>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("input[name=test]").change(function () {
                // check if child box is checked in first section
                var area1 = $("#area1").children("input[name=test]:checked");
                // check if child box is checked in second section
                var area2 = $("#area2").children("input[name=test]:checked");

                var isValid = (area1.length >= 1 && area2.length >= 1);

                if (isValid)
                    alert("valid");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `input type="radio"` element for `input type="checkbox"` elements; use `fieldset` element to contain `input` elements, add `disabled` attribute to `input type="submit"` element and `input type="radio"` elements that are not `:checked` with `.prop()`; remove `disabled` attribute when an `input` within a `fieldset` is `:checked` using `.is()` to check state of `input type="radio"` elements within a given `fieldset` parent element.

```js
$(".next").prop("disabled", true);

$("fieldset").each(function() {
  if (!$(":checked", this).is("*")) {
    $(this).addClass("notChecked")
  }
});

$("form").change(function() {
  var bool = false;
  var checked = $(".req").each(function(i, el) {
    bool = $(":radio", this).is(":checked")
  });
  if (bool) {
    $(".next[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
  };
  $("fieldset:has(:checked)").removeClass("notChecked")
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  width: 150px;
}
fieldset.notChecked {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
fieldset.notChecked:after {
  content: "Required";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form>
  <fieldset class="req">
    <label>Heading 1</label><br>
    <input type="radio" />
    <input type="radio" />
    <input type="radio" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="req">
    <label>Heading 2</label><br>
    <input type="radio" />
    <input type="radio" />
    <input type="radio" />
  </fieldset>
  <input class="next" type="submit" />
</form>
```